# I want the night light applet from GNOME shell 3.24

Tags: software-recommendation, gnome-shell

I'm a Web Developer, working on my Ubuntu 16.04 and I want to update to Ubuntu 17.04 in order to install new gnome-shell version 3.24 just because I really want that new features such as the night light applet, I've tried using flux app but it doesn't work. I've searched for a working alternative but I didn't have any luck.

Comment: Did you try installing `redshift`, then using your [Latitude & Longitude](https://mynasadata.larc.nasa.gov/latitudelongitude-finder/) to set your location?  Then use the settings of `6500` for daylight and `3700` for night?  The command would look like `redshift -l LAT:LONG -t 6500:3700`

Comment: @Terrance please add that as an answer so I can give you more points

Comment: Glad that it works for you.  Added an answer.  =)

Comment: I edited the question to ask about your real problem, based on your acceptance of Terrance's answer. Hopefully reviewers will not close it now. Please re-edit if you can clarify or you disagree with my changes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can install `redshift` from the following command:

```
sudo apt install redshift
```

You can just add `redshift` to your startup if you are OK with `redshift` pulling its own default settings. Or, you can configure it manually like I have laid out below.

---

You can get your Longitude & Latitude from https://www.latlong.net/

You can then create a config file that `redshift` will use in your home folder at `~/.config/redshift.conf`.  Add the following lines to it, and I added the `lat` and `lon` for Portland, OR.  But you can add the ones for your location.  Make sure to set `location-provider=` to `manual` then if you want to use the LAT and LONG.  However, the application `geoclue2` should be able to find your location.  Change the `temp-day` and `temp-night` to your likings.

*~/.config/redshift.conf*

```
; Global settings
[redshift]
temp-day=6500K
temp-night=3500
transition=1
gamma=1.000:1.000:1.000
location-provider=geoclue2
adjustment-method=randr

; The location provider and adjustment method settings
; are in their own sections.
; These are the location for Portland, OR.
[manual]
lat=45.523062
lon=-122.676482
```

Then all you have to do is to add just the application of `redshift -c ~/.config/redshift.conf` to your startup applications and it will use your config file at startup by default.

You can check your `redshift` parameters by running `redshift -pv` or `redshift -p`:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ redshift -pv
Location: 45.55 N, 122.68 W
Temperatures: 6500K at day, 3500K at night
Solar elevations: day above 3.0, night below -6.0
Brightness: 1.00:1.00
Gamma (Daytime): 1.000, 1.000, 1.000
Gamma (Night): 1.000, 1.000, 1.000
Solar elevation: -22.482371
Period: Night
Color temperature: 3500K
Brightness: 1.00



terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ redshift -p
Period: Night
Color temperature: 3500K
Brightness: 1.00
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: what a great answer, thank you! this helped a lot! awesme!

Comment: You can also change in the `redshift.conf` file, `location-provider=` to `location-provider=manual` to actually use the LAT and LON for your location to be more precise.  The `lat` and `lon` numbers have to be in their own section for it to work.  See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/redshift#Manual_setup

Answer (score 0):

A new simple and free software is [Iris mini](https://iristech.co/iris-mini/)
,all you have to do is open it (as it's in appimage format)

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one monitor then [eyesome](https://github.com/WinEunuuchs2Unix/eyesome) might work better for you than redshift, nightlight or Windows 10 as it provides separate brightness and gamma (color temperature) for three monitors.

Instead of Longitude and Latitude you enter your city name and country name, which is usually derived automatically. Sunrise and sunset times are obtained daily for your city. Then over a one to two hour period (more or less) which you define brightness and color temperature is gradually increased after sunrise and decreased before sunset so it unnoticeable.

Even for adaptive brightness TVs you might prefer turning the feature off cranking up the brightness on the TV and using eyesome to control brightness instead.

I wrote it and it's all in bash so you can change it for more monitors (than 3) or for Windows 10 or whatever.

### Sample screenshots

[image: eyesome main menu.png]

[image: eyesome edit.png]

[image: eyesome-edit-configuration-general.png]

[image: eyesome-edit-configuration-monitor1.png]

[image: eyesome-edit-configuration-monitor3.png]