# Night light not working

Tags: 18.04, system-settings

I have already tried the solution provided in [Nightlight has stopped working 18.04.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085311/nightlight-has-stopped-working-18-04-1?rq=1), but it isn't working for me.
In settings, I'm getting the option to turn the night light on or off, and I'm also getting the option to set the night light intensity, but when I'm turning the night light on, nothing happens.
I have uploaded the pictures, you can see no colour change is happening on the screen.
**When the night light is off**
[image: when the night light is off]
**When the night light is set to automatic**
[image: when the night light is set to automatic]
**When the night light is set to manual**
[image: when the night light is set to manual]

**There is nothing happening on the screen.

I'll be thankful for the help.

Thank-you**

Comment: It happened to me too. I have it set to manual timing, from 05:00 to 04:59. When it broke, even the nightlight icon did not show up in the panel. But I noticed that my monitors (laptop + external HDMI) have disappeared from the _Settings_ app's _Color_ settings sidebar item. I set the preinstalled `D50` color profile for my laptop's screen on that _Color_ settings UI. But now only my printer had shown up to set a color profile to: the monitors did not. I think it's related. A reboot however restored everything: the _Color_ settings UI, the laptop screen color profile, and night light.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using:
5.3.0-7648-generic #41~1586790036~18.04~600aeb5~dev-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 13 17:49:24  x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Night light needs at least a 1 hour time difference if you are using manual settings.  I ran into this problem and thought my machine was broken. (I always use night light mode).  The issue was I had selected times inside a 60 minute difference.
So the simple solution is make sure the manual settings for night light are at least 60 minutes between night mode and day mode:

My settings:
From 05:45 to 04:45

When I set my "to" setting at 04:46, night light shut off.